# Looking to swap a card view onClick - best way of doing it?

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android so sorry if this is obvious.

I currently have a few cards that I would like to display extra information when clicked. At the moment they have 6 lines of text and a couple of pictures. I want to display one line of text when the card is pressed and go back when it is pressed again.

The plan I have at the moment is to have 2 identical in size cards and set the visibility of one to gone and when the other is clicked set it to gone and make the other one visible. Is this the best way of doing this? For example, I could use one card and just swap the content.

Thanks for any advice in advance

edit - I'd also like to add some kind of transition - maybe a fade between them so ideally this would be possible too

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
        <ImageView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Replace with

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

where the text view is different. I'm basically asking if I should make an entirely new card of just hide all the other text/imageviews and show the new one. I hope I've explained a bit better

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @End.Game I've added some simplified code

Comment: If you need to show components that already are in the card it has not sense create another one. Just make visible or not what you want. To me it's the best way